# Why does C++ allow a char array as an argument when it's expecting a string?

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


string combine(string a, string b, string c);

int main() {

    char name[10]   = {'J','O','H','N','\0'};
    string age      = "24";
    string location = "United Kingdom";


    cout << combine(name,age,location);

    return 0;

}

string combine(string a, string b, string c) {
    return a + b + c;
}
```

This compiles fine with no warnings or errors despite the combine function expecting a string and receiving a char array, is this because a string is stored as a char array?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string

Comment: `char name[10]   = {'J','O','H','N','\0'};` can be written much more simply as `char name[10] = "JOHN";`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why does C++ allow a char array as an argument when it's expecting a string?

Because `std::string` has such a conversion constructor, which supports implicit conversion of `char const*` into `std::string` object.

This is the constructor which is responsible for this conversion:

```
basic_string( const CharT* s, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

Have a look at [the documentation and other constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string).

Answer (score 1):

It's because there is an automatic conversion from a char array to a string.

`string` has a constructor like this (simplified)

```
class string
{
public:
    string(const char* s);
    ...
};
```

This constructor can be called automatically, so your code is equivalent to this

```
cout << combine(string(name),age,location);
```